# OpenSSL C API Decryption doesn't work sometimes

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I have been playing around with some of the OpenSSL examples (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_CipherInit_ex.html#EXAMPLES)

I modified the example a little to encrypt a string instead of reading from a file. It seems to work sometimes and not other times.

Here is the code, Hopefully this link works: https://godbolt.org/z/v5W18a

If not, the code is below

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

inline void print_error()
{
  const auto error_code = ERR_get_error();

  std::cout << "ERR_lib_error_string " << ERR_lib_error_string(error_code) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "ERR_func_error_string " << ERR_func_error_string(error_code) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "ERR_reason_error_string " << ERR_reason_error_string(error_code) << std::endl;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> do_crypt(std::string in, int& outlen, int do_encrypt)
 {
     /* Allow enough space in output buffer for additional block */
     std::vector<unsigned char> outbuf;
     outbuf.resize(1024 + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH);

     EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
     /*
      * Bogus key and IV: we'd normally set these from
      * another source.
      */
     unsigned char key[] = "0123456789abcdeF";
     unsigned char iv[] = "1234567887654321";

     /* Don't set key or IV right away; we want to check lengths */
     ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
     EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL,
                       do_encrypt);
     OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(ctx) == 16);
     OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(ctx) == 16);

     /* Now we can set key and IV */
     EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv, do_encrypt);

     EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 1);

     
    if (!EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, outbuf.data(), &outlen, (const unsigned char*) in.data(), in.size())) {
        /* Error */
        print_error();
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return {};
    }
    
    if (!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf.data(), &outlen)) {
         /* Error */
         print_error();
         EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
         return {};
    }

     EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
     return outbuf;
 }


int main()
{
    int outlen = 0;
    auto out = do_crypt("Hello world", outlen, 1);
    
    std::string outs(out.begin(), out.begin() + outlen);
    
    std::cout << "Encrypted " << outs << std::endl;

    auto out2 = do_crypt(outs, outlen, 0);
    
    std::string outs2(out2.begin(), out2.begin() + outlen);
    
    std::cout << "Decrypted " << outs2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It encrypts and decrypts "Hello World"

```
Program returned: 0
Encrypted �5n��վ���m*��ׂ
Decrypted Hello world
```

But let's say I try

```
auto out = do_crypt("Hello world! How are you?", outlen, 1);
```

I get a bad decrypt error

```
Program returned: 0
Encrypted ��!p�
�Y2�,�C
ERR_lib_error_string digital envelope routines
ERR_func_error_string EVP_DecryptFinal_ex
ERR_reason_error_string bad decrypt
Decrypted
```

1. What is causing the bad decrypt? Why is a bigger string causing a bad decrypt?

Also if you disable padding,

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);
```

And do some string like

```
auto out = do_crypt("Some Crypto Text", outlen, 1);
```

The result is just blank with not error output

```
Program returned: 0
Encrypted 
Decrypted
```

Add one more character to that string and we have a segfault with a "data not multiple of block length"

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: In `EVP_CipherFinal_ex()` `outbuf.data() + outlen` must be used. Also, the values of `outlen` from `EVP_CipherUpdate()` and `EVP_CipherFinal_ex()` must be added and this value must be returned, see [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption#Authenticated_Encryption_using_GCM_mode).

Comment: @Topaco Thanks! that was the issue, I can't believe I missed that on the first example in the link I provided, I went straight for the second example... Thanks again!